# C++ STD find_last_of not working?

Tags: c++, string, std

I'm trying to write a function that cleans a string from preceeding or trailing whitespaces.

So basically, if you pass it the function `"   \tHello, this is a test!     \t"` then it will must return `"Hello, this is a test!"`. Here's my code, but...

```
string clean_str(string str)
{
    const string alphabet("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890åäö-");

    size_t first = str.find_first_of(alphabet);
    size_t last = str.find_last_of(alphabet);
    return str.substr(first, last);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string s("         test 123-4    ");
    cout << "[" << clean_str(s) << "]";
    Sleep(INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

It returns

```
// s == "test 123-4    "
```

Which is wrong. I've decided to go with Boost anyway, but I still want to know why this doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the second argument to [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) - it's supposed to be a count of the number of characters in the substring. That means you should do:

```
return str.substr(first, last - first + 1);
```

Make sure you always read the documentation for a function you're using (perhaps until you know it off by heart).

Comment: The fundamantal problem is that `std::string` came from a different library than the STL.  So it has very different interface conventions.

Comment: @Yakk `std::string` is a mess.

Comment: Oh and if the string is `"  a  "` the above returns the empty string.

Comment: Oops, hadn't noticed that.

Comment: You're right, this is the kind of hubris you get sometimes. Disregarding all the simple things. Thank you!

Comment: And now it also throws on `"   "` -- check for `npos`!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
return ( first == std::string::npos ? "" : str.substr(first, last + 1 - first ) );
```

The second argument specifies the number of characters that should be extracted.

Comment: @ Yakk Of course he should check whether first == last.

Comment: @Vlad Not quite. For "a" as an input `first` and `last` are both 0. The result string should be "a" though.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi You are right. The first and last must be compared with npos. I will uodate my post.